# SQL Unable to Insert Additional Condition

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Below is my SQL query:

```
var staffLeaves = (from staffLeave in db.StaffLeaves
                   join leavetype in db.LeaveTypes
                   on staffLeave.LeaveID equals leavetype.LeaveTypeID

                   join staff in db.Staffs
                   on staffLeave.StaffID equals staff.StaffID
                   where staffLeave.Year == latest_year.Year

                   //new insertion start

                   join jobinfo in db.JobInfo
                   on staffLeave.StaffID equals jobinfo.staff_id
                   where jobinfo.last_date == null
         error --> OR jobinfo.last_date > DateTime.Now

                   //new insertion end

                   orderby leavetype.Description ascending

                   select new { staffLeave = staffLeave, staff = staff, leavetype = leavetype }).AsQueryable();
```

May I know how can I put in the additional condition `OR jobinfo.last_date > DateTime.Now`?

Or do I need to implement another `join` statement with the same table but with the 2nd condition this time.

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2014.

Thank you.

Comment: Pls. add your DB name like SQL SERVER,ORACLE,MYSQL etc

Comment: okay, I will add it in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var staffLeaves = (from staffLeave in db.StaffLeaves
                   from leavetype in db.LeaveTypes
                   from staff in db.Staffs
                   from jobinfo in db.JobInfo
                   where staffLeave.LeaveID == leavetype.LeaveTypeID && 
                   staffLeave.LeaveID == leavetype.LeaveTypeID && 
                   staffLeave.Year == latest_year.Year &&
                   staffLeave.StaffID == jobinfo.staff_id &&
                   (jobinfo.last_date == null || jobinfo.last_date > DateTime.Now)
                   orderby leavetype.Description ascending
                   select new { staffLeave = staffLeave, staff = staff, leavetype = leavetype }).AsQueryable();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var staffLeaves = (from staffLeave in db.StaffLeaves
               join leavetype in db.LeaveTypes
               on staffLeave.LeaveID equals leavetype.LeaveTypeID

               join staff in db.Staffs
               on staffLeave.StaffID equals staff.StaffID
               where staffLeave.Year == latest_year.Year

               //new insertion start

               join jobinfo in db.JobInfo
               on (staffLeave.StaffID equals jobinfo.staff_id and jobinfo.last_date == null and jobinfo.last_date > DateTime.Now)


               //new insertion end

               orderby leavetype.Description ascending

               select new { staffLeave = staffLeave, staff = staff, leavetype = leavetype }).AsQueryable();
```

> so i have added the where condition inside the join